# Jenkins DSL autocomplete: custom jobs folder name

Tags: jenkins, intellij-idea, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to configure IntelliJ Idea autocomplete for Jenkins DSL pipelines.
Autocomplete works perfect if I keep my pipelines in `jobs` folder.
However, I need to use another name for `jobs` directory (because of historical reasons). For example, when I rename `jobs` to `jobs1`, autocomplete stops working.
How to cofigure DSL autocomplete for arbitrary jobs directory? Thank you in advance!

Project structure:

```
jobs1/
    job1.groovy
    idea.gdsl
build.gradle
```

Content of `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
sourceSets {
    jobs {
        groovy {
            srcDirs 'jobs1'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/' }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.8'
    implementation "org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:1.77"
}
```

Versions: Idea 2021.2.2, Gradle 7.2, Groovy 3.0.8

Answer (score 3):

*Found the answer while publishing the question. Just share it:*
The `jobs` directory was specified in `idea.gdsl` file:

```
def ctx = context(pathRegexp: /.*\/jobs\/.*groovy/)
contributor(ctx, {
    delegatesTo(findClass('javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory'))
})
```

So, I replaced regexp `/.*\/jobs\/.*groovy/` with `/.*\/*\/.*groovy/`, and now autocomplete works in any directories:

```
def ctx = context(pathRegexp: /.*\/*\/.*groovy/)
contributor(ctx, {
    delegatesTo(findClass('javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory'))
})
```